# Specifying a custom node id when creating new content

Tags: nodes, 8, database

I want to prevent merge conflicts caused by POST requests on the API at a later stage. Is it possible to specify a custom node id when creating new content in the Drupal user interface or database? What's the fastest, most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UI no, and you should never interact with the database directly.

But you can do this with the API easily:

```
$node = Node::create(['type' => 'article', 'nid' => 5]);
$node->enforceIsNew(TRUE);
$node->save();
```