# Can You Use HOOK_node_builder() to Set Custom Node ID?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

Drupal 8.x

How do you set the node id in HOOK_node_builder()? Is it even possible?

There is a similar question here: [Specifying a custom node id when creating new content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222845/specifying-a-custom-node-id-when-creating-new-content), however it is a different approach or need.

**MYMODULE.module**:

```
function MYMODULE_node_builder($entity_type, NodeInterface $node, $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $node->setTitle('Node Title');

}
```

I am able to set the title fine. I am hard pressed to find any docs or posts on this hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no HOOK_node_builder, here are the available hooks in the [Entity API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/).

I think [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave) is the one you are looking for.

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  $node->nid->value = 5;
  $node->enforceIsNew(TRUE);
}
```

[Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_crud) is the order of hooks and other events that happen during an entity save:

- preSave() is called on the entity object, and field objects.
- hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()
- hook_entity_presave()
- Entity is saved to storage.
- For updates on content entities, if there is a translation added that was not previously present:

  - hook_ENTITY_TYPE_translation_insert()
  - hook_entity_translation_insert()
- For updates on content entities, if there was a translation removed:

  - hook_ENTITY_TYPE_translation_delete()
  - hook_entity_translation_delete()
- postSave() is called on the entity object.
- hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert() (new) or hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update() (update)
- hook_entity_insert() (new) or hook_entity_update() (update)

Comment: Do you have an idea why this hook works?

Comment: It's not a hook, it's a callback you can add to $form['#entity_builders'], see [EntityForm::buildEntity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityForm.php/function/EntityForm%3A%3AbuildEntity/8.6.x)

Comment: @4k4, in this case, I think both methods work, but `hook_node_presave` is shorter/easier to implement.

Comment: @Prestosaurus, I added a short explanation and a link to the official documentation.